# Opinion on editing community-wiki posts

Tags: discussion

That [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/is-anybody-using-tex-for-business-reporting/3507#3507) is wrong about using ConTeXt in a commercial environment. Now there are several options: a) post a comment below that this is not true, b) edit that community wiki post to delete that comment, c) edit the wiki post and say [edit: this is not true] or d) ...?

What is your opinion on that subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reputation system works pretty good in this respect -- if people think that a particular answer is wrong, they should downvote it, and that basically solves the problem. If the answer does have a grain of truth and only some of the facts are wrong (i.e. the post does not have misinformation intent), then editing should be a better solution. Commenting always helps, though, and that should be used in any such case.

Comment: Yes, the reputation system does the magic, that's true. Probably the best is to wait some time and then act if nothing happens. (=leave a comment)